# react-transition-group show child component with animation and delay after parent is rendered

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, parent-child, react-transition-group

How can I animate-in a child component after the parent is rendered with `react-transition-group`?

I would like to show the Child Component as the parent is getting rendered with delay and some kind of animation for example slide-up.

```
  <CSSTransition
              in={true}
              timeout={2000}
              classNames="show-indicator"
              transitionName="show-indicator"
            >
              <Indicator /> //this is my child component
  </CSSTransition>
```

at this moment no class will be set